# How to get different count of key php array to table and

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array[1] = array("Name1"=> array("2"=>"1460","3"=>"1868","4"=>"2158","5"=>"2537","6"=>"2915","8"=>"3673"));
$array[2] = array("Prod2"=> array("3"=>"3079","4"=>"3625","5"=>"4172","6"=>"4718","8"=>"5811"));
$cnt = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++) {    
    $product = $array[$x]; // dynamic all product`s - $name
    foreach ($product as $good =>$massiv) {
        $name = key($product);      // prod name
        $proklkadok = array_keys($massiv);  // prod prokladok
        foreach ($massiv as $inner_key =>$price) {
            echo "<tr><td>". $name. "</td>";
            $pr_val = array_keys($massiv);
            echo "<td>".$pr_val[0]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$price."</td></tr>\r\n"; // product price
        }  
    }
}
```

how to print `$pr_val` unique in table td cell ?
This code is wrong, bad table prints the output:

```
Name1   2   1138    or wrong output too ...   Name1  2,3,4,5,6,8    1138
Name1   2   1868    or wrong output too ...   Name1  2,3,4,5,6,8    1868
Name1   2   2158    or wrong output too ...   Name1  2,3,4,5,6,8    2158
Prod2   3   3079    or wrong output too ...   Prod2  2,3,4,5,6,8    3079
Prod2   3   3625    or wrong output too ...   Prod2  2,3,4,5,6,8    3625
Prod2   3   4718    or wrong output too ...   Prod2  2,3,4,5,6,8    4718    
Prod2   3   5811    or wrong output too ...   Prod2  2,3,4,5,6,8    5811
```

Correct output must be in HTML TABLE

```
Name1   2   1138
Name1   3   1868 
Name1   4   2158 
Name1   5   2537
Name1   6   2915
Name1   8   3673

Prod2   3   3079
Prod2   4   3079
Prod2   5   3625
Prod2   6   4718    
Prod2   8   5811
```

pls help me, I can't count and output different count of array keys in the table output

Answer (score 2):

The bug is at

```
$pr_val = array_keys($massiv);
echo "<td>".$pr_val[0]. "</td>";
```

`array_key($massiv)` returns **all** keys of `massiv` and `$pr_val[0]`always returns the first of them (which happens to be the smallest of them).

Try

```
foreach($product as $good =>$massiv) {

    foreach($massiv as $inner_key =>$price) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $good. "</td>";

        echo "<td>".$inner_key. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$price."</td></tr>\r\n"; // product price
    }  
}
```

That should output exactly what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This code will output what you desire as the correct output in an HTML table

```
$array[1]=array("Name1"=> array("2"=>"1460","3"=>"1868","4"=>"2158","5"=>"2537","6"=>"2915","8"=>"3673"));
$array[2] =array("Prod2"=> array("3"=>"3079","4"=>"3625","5"=>"4172","6"=>"4718","8"=>"5811"));
echo "<table>" . PHP_EOL;
foreach($array as $product) {    
    foreach($product as $name =>$massiv) {
        foreach($massiv as $inner_key => $price) {
            echo "<tr><td>". $name. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$inner_key. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$price."</td></tr>" . PHP_EOL; // product price
        }  
    }
}
echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: To make a high quality answer, you should explain what the problem was with the original code, and what you changed to fix it. Don't just dump new code with no explanation.

Comment: eoe thanks thats great! but is not all, see you later my dear frined!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = array("Name1"=> array("2"=>"1460","3"=>"1868","4"=>"2158","5"=>"2537","6"=>"2915","8"=>"3673"));
$array[1] = array("Prod2"=> array("3"=>"3079","4"=>"3625","5"=>"4172","6"=>"4718","8"=>"5811"));
echo '<table rules="all" border="1">';
foreach($array as $v) {
    foreach($v as $name => $ar) {
        foreach($ar as $v1 => $v2) {
            echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>'."\r\n",
                $name, $v1, $v2);
        }
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

by Prizma